# What is the best open source middleware for Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I'm looking for best middlewire software for Ubuntu (like Jboss for Redhat). I need a middlewire for deploying Ubuntu on enterprise environment. Hope this answer gonna be helpful for many people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> Arquillian is a platform that simplifies Java middleware testing. ...
>   it might be a good fit as a replacement data store for metrics.<sup>1</sup>

For detailed info see [JBoss Community](http://www.jboss.org/)

Also it might be helpful to look at this: [Open Source and Linux from HP](http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/cache/321150-0-0-0-121.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Jboss](http://www.jboss.org/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's great to know that Jboss can be implemented on Ubuntu, but is there any other alternative like Jboss.